# move string starting with specific characters into another column in pandas df

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe containing addresses.

| Addressess |
| --- |
| 10 Pentland Drive, Comiston, Edinburgh, EH10 6PX. |
| Moray Place, Edinburgh, EH3 |
| Carlton Street, Edinburgh |
| The Bourse Apartments, 47 Timber Bush, Leith EH6 6QH |

I wish to write code in python and pandas that identifies if there is an 'EH' in the row and then moves this and all subsequent characters into another column. Thus achieving this:

| Addressess | Post Code |
| --- | --- |
| 10 Pentland Drive, Comiston, Edinburgh, . | EH10 6PX |
| Moray Place, Edinburgh, | EH3 |
| Carlton Street, Edinburgh |  |
| The Bourse Apartments, 47 Timber Bush, Leith EH6 6QH | EH6 6QH |

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df[['Addressess', 'Post Code']] = df['Addressess'].str.extract(r'(.*?)\s*(\bEH\d+[\s\w]*)?\W*$')
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kJgOTH/1)

Or [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), if there is at least one row with a post code:

```
df[['Addressess', 'Post Code']] = df['Addressess'].str.split(r'\s*(?=\bEH\d*)', n=1, expand=True)
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vTBX7z/1)

Output:

```
                                     Addressess Post Code
0       10 Pentland Drive, Comiston, Edinburgh,  EH10 6PX
1                       Moray Place, Edinburgh,       EH3
2                     Carlton Street, Edinburgh       NaN
3  The Bourse Apartments, 47 Timber Bush, Leith   EH6 6QH
```

Answer (score 0):

With simple regex matching:

```
df['Post Code'] = df['Addressess'].str.extract('(EH.+)').fillna('')
```

---

```
                                          Addressess  Post Code
0  10 Pentland Drive, Comiston, Edinburgh, EH10 6PX.  EH10 6PX.
1                        Moray Place, Edinburgh, EH3        EH3
2                          Carlton Street, Edinburgh           
3  The Bourse Apartments, 47 Timber Bush, Leith E...    EH6 6QH
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using a regex positive lookahead:

```
df['Addressess'].str.split(r'[0-9A-Za-z,] (?=EH)',expand=True).rename({0:'Addressess',1:'Post Code'},axis=1)
```